# Why does my mesh have no faces on the inside?

Tags: faces

[image]

How can I fix the interior of the mesh?

Answer (score 3):

No worries, your mesh is fine. Just disable the visibility in the modifier tab and you can see it without the effect.

[image: Subdivision]

Answer (score 0):

In the Viewport Display panel enable

- Wireframe
- Display all edges